# Options for sharing an entityframework datacontext between .NET framework and .NET core

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have an existing solution with .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects in it. This includes a seperate data access layer (DAL), business logic and web layers.
The DAL is using EntityFramework 6.

I would like to add new .NET 8 web application projects to the solution. I understand I cannot just reference the DAL project from the new .NET 8 projects.

I am unsure what my options are for any kind of code sharing.
e.g. will i have to create a new DAL layer that uses EntityFrameworkCore 8 which the new projects will reference. I will then have to maintain 2 datacontexts and pick one that handles the migrations?

Would it be possible to refactor/move all the table classes (DbSets) to a .NET Standard 2.0 class library and share these between the datacontexts. This would help maintaining both DAL's. Is using a .NET 2.0 class librabry the right way to share code between .NET Framework and CORE?

Are there any other options I can use?

I have tried creating a new EntityFrameworkCore DAL and automatically scafolding it using "Scaffold-DbContext" This worked OK but seems like a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: .NET 8 is .NET *Core* 8. Microsoft dropped the `Core` part in .NET 5 for marketing reasons.  [EF 6.3 and later](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.3.0) support .NET Core through multi-targeting, not .NET Standard 2.0. Your assembly should be modified to target both runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing dbcontext between .NET framework and .NET Core can be challenging due to platform differences. However .NET standard library can be created which can be shared .NET Core and .NET Framework. Alternatively conditional compilation directives can be used to include / exlcude platform specific code for eg

```
#if NETCOREAPP
    public SharedDbContext CreateDbContext(DbContextOptions<SharedDbContext> options) => new SharedDbContext(options);
#endif

#if NETFRAMEWORK
    public SharedDbContext CreateDbContext() => new SharedDbContext();
#endif
```

Also other factors which needs to considered is complexity of the project.But thorough testing needs to be carried out on both the platforms.